# How to integrate stack navigator,TabNavigator,Drawer Navigator togather in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to use the Navigator All togather but i fail to implement this  the code which i use for integration is

```
const MyApp = const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: HomeButton,
  },
},
DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: list,
  },
  SwipeList:{
    screen:SwipeLists
  },
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  contentComponent: SideDrawer,
});
});
const Simple = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
  },
  signup: {
    screen: SignUp,
  },
  forget:{
    screen:forget
  },
});
```

I use this above but this is not correct i am not now how to integrate them plz recmond the way how to integrate the three navigator in react native

Comment: Guys any one can pls help us i'm also have same issue . I too asked same question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404614/integrate-stack-drawer-and-tab-navigator-in-react-native

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: yes I resolve it on that time