# Integrate Stack, Drawer and Tab Navigator in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have tried to implement Stack, Drawer and Tab Navigator together in a single project but it's not working what I expected. First, created tab navigator, one is Home and another one is  Careers.  Next, creating Stack Navigator and integrate drawer as root in NavigationApp. Next, Creating Drawer Navigator integrate AppDrawer as root.

[image]

```js
    import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
    import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
    import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
    import Register from './src/Register'
    import Home from './src/Home'
    import Products from './src/Products'
    import Openings from './src/Openings'
    import CareersPortal from './src/CareersPortal'
    export default class PageNavigation extends Component {
    render()
    {
     return (
     <NavigationApp/>  ); 
    }
    }


     const AppTab=TabNavigator({
     Home:{screen :Home },
     CareersPortal:{screen : CareersPortal},
     });



     const NavigationApp =StackNavigator({
     Openings:{screen:Openings},
     Register:{screen:Register},
     Home :{ screen: AppDrawer},
     });



     const AppDrawer= DrawerNavigator({
     Home:{screen: AppTab},
     Products:{screen :Products},
     }); 
     AppRegistry.registerComponent('PageNavigation', () => NavigationApp);


  Not integrated properly can anyone help me
```

Comment: Follow the issue https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/571

Comment: thanks it's working when we use tab and stack navigator alone. But I have to use tab,drawer and stack navigator

Answer (score 0):

You can use this structure that I found really handy whit react-navigation v3x

- AppSwitchNavigator

  - AppDrawerNavigator

    - DashboardStackNavigator

      - DashboardTabNavigator

You can see this video that can explain you in much detail the answer you want.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w24FE9PZpzk